# form_for > f.submit, How to only alert at update action.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would one set this up so it only pop's up at update action and not create?

`= f.submit, data: { confirm: "you are about to update object, are you sure?" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
= f.submit, data: action == 'edit' ? { confirm: "you are about to update object, are you sure?" } : {}
```

Comment: that through a syntax error, not sure where it went wrong.
This is a long solution, I had syntax problems so that's why it has so many lines :) 
`-if @quiz.persisted?
       = f.submit class: "btn-lg btn-primary", data: { confirm: t(:are_you_sure) }
 -else
        = f.submit class: "btn-lg btn-primary"`

Comment: Try
`= @quiz.persisted? ? f.submit class: "btn-lg btn-primary", data: { confirm: t(:are_you_sure) } : f.submit class: "btn-lg btn-primary"`

Comment: That's exactly what I have tried but that has some weird syntax error.

Comment: I don't see any in this fragment. Maybe somewhere else?

Comment: Anyways I'll accept your answer as correct because you led me to the solution.

Comment: Yes the error was produced by that line for sure :)